# How to transfer serialized data to the server and deserelize it

Tags: c++, networking, serialization

I use the enet library to write the client and server side of the code, and also decided to use the boost library to serialize the data. I used something like this code to send data and serialize it

```
        char message_data[80] = "somedata";
        std::stringstream ss;
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa{ ss };
        oa << message_data;
        SendPacket(peer, ss.str());
```

and something like this code for getting data and deserializing it

```
                std::string deser_data;
                std::string some_data = (char*)event.packet->data;
                std::stringstream ss(some_data);
                boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia{ ss };
                ia >> deser_data;
```

But this code does not work, I think it is due to incorrect use of stringstream, but this is not accurate

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you want to use a binary (non-portable, change-intolerant) representation? JSON has become a bit of a standard. Be that as it may...

I would add some debug. What length are you writing? What length are you reading? If you dump the buffers, are they identical on client and server?

Does the code work if you do it all inline (no network involved)? That is, can you write a unit test to do both the client and server side where you construct an object, serialize it, deserialize into another object, and then compare them?

I'd start with that.

Sorry, this isn't a proper answer, but it's too long for a simple comment.

Comment: I tried to debug everything seemed to work fine, but maybe I missed something, so I decided to contact here so that people can show how to do what I want

Comment: I'd consider the size of the buffer -- are you sure you're getting all the data in a single read?

Comment: `Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE6FD93B19 in server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::archive::archive_exception at memory location 0x000000FD5050F1C0.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE6FD93B19 in server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::archive::archive_exception at memory location 0x000000FD5050F1C0.` I get this error when I try to read the data received from the client